# How to load and process the data as MAP pig?

Tags: dictionary, apache-pig

I have the data in the following format:

```
isotimestamp source service info serviceid msg hostname requsetid

2013-08-22T13:23:18.226220+01:00  indiana  service2q  info  255  " processing  
request "  host1   e2cerd22
```

I was able to convert the ISO timestamp to datetime by UDF. The messages are separated by spaces and the length of message is not constant. When I try to load the data by `pig-storage('')` (as the message bits are separated by spaces), it is retrieving the next bit of message as other column data.

In the above example if I generate hostname, it gives me the request bit of the message. Is there any specific way to handle such data as MAP in Pig? I tried to use `TO-MAP` but failed to achieve the required map conversion.

```
tomapdata = FOREACH data GENERATE  myudf.test(dt)as date, 
            TOMAP(source,service,info,serviceid,msg,hostname,requestid)as m;

getdata = FOREACH tomapdata GENERATE dt, m#hostname, m#serviceid;
```

Is it possible to load the date as `chararray` and remaining portion of data as a map?

```
load 'data.log' as (dt:chararray , m:MAP[chararray] ); 
Foreach data generate m#source ;
```

**Questions :**

Can any one guide me in loading the data as MAP in pig ?
Can anyone provide some suggestions on load/process the data as MAP in Pig?

**Required Map :

```
source#indiana 

service#service2q

msg#"processing  request" 

hostname#host1

requestid#ec2cerd22**
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge you cannont use any of the built in functions to load that data as a map, due to the lack of [ ] in the file that would show map beginning and map end.

That being said I think I have figured out why your TOMAP is failing. A map is composed of key value pairs, and the input of TOMAP must therefore be an even number, as it takes every first column as a key, and every second column as a value. Your TOMAP has exactly seven arguments, leaving the last value argument missing. If you want all of the data to be associated with one key you coule do the following:

(for example purposes source is assumed to be key)

> tomapdata = FOREACH data GENERATE  myudf.test(dt)as date, 
>               TOMAP(source,TOTUPLE(service,info,serviceid,msg,hostname,requestid))as
>   m;

This would have source for the key, and a tuple of everything else as the value.

If you simply forgot to add a column just add that one in at the end of the TOMAP and it should work.

If you are instead trying to simply get everything as a set, and having it in key-value pairs doesn't matter you might just be able to use TOTUPLE or TOBAG.

Comment: Broada Thanks a lot How to generate the key value pairs when i try to do as below iam popped up with Cannot cast chararray to map with schema source:map error ** FOREACH data GENERATE myudf.test(dt)as date,source#'service'; **

Answer (score 0):

As best I can tell, your problem is not in creating the map but the fact that you wish for Pig to respect `"` marks in your data and not split on the spaces in between them.  If you know that `msg` is the only field that is going to have quotes like that, here's a hack:

```
predata = LOAD 'input' USING PigStorage('"') AS (initial:chararray, msg:chararray, final:chararray);
data =
    FOREACH predata
    GENERATE
        FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(initial, ' ', 5) AS (
            isotimestamp:chararray,
            source:chararray,
            service:chararray,
            info:chararray,
            serviceid:chararray),
        msg,
        FLATTEN(STRSPLIT(final, ' ', 2) AS (
            hostname:chararray,
            requestid:chararray);
```

And away you go.  You have no need for a map.

Answer (score 0):

I was liking Davis Broda's answer to this but sadly tried something similar with the following:

```
----sample_data.txt
open,apache,another,pig
open,apache,apache,pig
apache,hadoop

----my.pig
A = LOAD '$input' AS chararray;
B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    STRSPLIT($0,',').$0 AS myvals:chararray
    , TOMAP(STRSPLIT($0,',').$0,STRSPLIT($0,',').$1) AS mymap:map [(i:chararray)];
-- this fails   , TOMAP(STRSPLIT($0,',')) AS mymap:map [(i:chararray)];
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $1#'open';
DUMP C;
DESCRIBE C;

$>pig -x local -param input=sample_data.txt my.pig
(apache)
(apache)
()
C: {(i: chararray)}
```

but unfortunately, although the output of STRSPLIT is a tuple, I get an empty map object and no values out. It seems dynamic map creation is not perhaps permitted on pig 0.11